# memory cards capacity needs to be the same?

Tags: memory

I am not a hardware guy. I just heard this from a service engineer

Memory cards of unequal capacities should not be used. that is if there is a 1 GB already in the slot, we need to add another 1 GB card only. Not 512 MB or 2 GB.

Is there a problem if we use memory cards which are not equal capacities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a [dual channel architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-channel_architecture), matching memory modules are recommended for best performance and compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix and match different sizes; I have commonly used 1 GB and .5 GB together to get 1.5 GB total.  But you don't get dual channel performance.  So I probably wouldn't add a 256 or 512 MB to a 2 GB, but I would to a 1.